# Execute stored procedure one at a time takes less, but when executed as batch of exec of the same stored proc takes more time

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure exec statement like this:-

```
---ABC DEF-------------------------------
--- (1)Batch Run 1:38 (2) 42 Seconds (3) 41 Sec (4) 41 Sec (5) 42 Seconds
exec usp_RS_DEALIO_JLL_ECRDetails 
       @dEmpID=N'990000:22085'
       ,@Year=N'2016'
       ,@CommPeriod=N'24 - 11/15/2016 - 11/30/2016'
       ,@BusinessLine=N'3'
       ,@MarketID=N'1201 - Midwest: Chicago Downtown'
       ,@OpUnitID=N'1502 - Brokerage: Leasing - Tenant Re;990000'
       ,@Prof=N'002701'
       ,@ShowPros=N'Yes'
       ,@ShowRecon=N'No'
```

This stored procedure runs about 45 seconds when executed in SSMS. However when I try running the same stored procedure in different SSMS window at the same time with different parameters, it takes more time.

In this case the parameters above it took 1:38 seconds. How can I bring it down to 45 seconds or so even when I have 10 exec stored procedure statements fired simultaneously in different windows in SSMS.

What I am actually trying to do here is, this stored procedure is fired through a console app which calls the SSRS Report Server. The SSRS Server calls the stored procedure to generate the report. The SSRS Report Server returns a timeout which results in corrupted PDF's. So I am trying to reduce the stored procedure time even when 10 requests are fired to SSRS Report Service to download binary to avoid a timeout.

Any suggestions and ideas are appreciated.

BTW - the stored procedure has the statement RECOMPILE which circumvents the parameter sniffing problem I think:-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RS_DEALIO_JLL_ECRDetails]                             
--DECLARE                                                                  
  @dEmpID NVARCHAR(50)                                                                                                                                                   
 ,@Year NVARCHAR(50)                                                                                                                                                  
 ,@CommPeriod NVARCHAR(50)                     
 ,@BusinessLine nvarchar(50)                                              
 ,@MarketID NVARCHAR(MAX)                              
 ,@OpUnitID NVARCHAR(MAX)                                                                   
 ,@Prof NVARCHAR(MAX)                     
 ,@ShowPros Nvarchar(Max)                       
 ,@ShowRecon Nvarchar(Max)                     
with Recompile                                                                                                                
AS
```

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing. Use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` in your SP and see if you get different results. Granted, it could take longer just based off the result set (more rows being returned, etc). If your query times get closer, then we'd have to look at the proc itself for performance enhancements.

Comment: @scsimon It does have the RECOMPILE in the stored procedure. I have put the code in the question.

Comment: Do you have nested procedures in this proc?

Comment: @scsimon - yes to answer your question.

Comment: Well, `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` will only affect the outer most proc, naturally, so you could be getting nested parameter sniffing in those procs. Those procs would have cached plans in `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`

Comment: @scsimon - what is the solution ?

Comment: Well, one option is placing `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` in those procs, or more precisely using it in your statements explicitly: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. Also, some queries may be locking the tables at points. There's just so much that *could* be going on. Have you checked the **actual** execution plans of each to see the differences?  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @scsimon - I do have RECOMPILE for inner procs. "EXEC [dbo].[usp_RS_GetOPUnit_Comm]  WITH RECOMPILE "

Comment: Ok, paste the plans if possible.